# How quickly do planetary rings form?

Tags: planet

Just a very general question, but I haven't seen this discussed elsewhere. If a moon gets busted up for some reason, say a collision with another moon, and is at the right orbital distance from its planet, how soon would you expect the debris cloud to be recognizable as a ring? I'm just looking for a ballpark answer: 10 thousand years, a million years, ten million, etc.

Comment: Have you seen the questions about how long rings last?

Comment: It's kind of the opposite question, but I looked at a couple. There was some discussion on the age of rings, but not specifically on when they form, especially when it happens after the formation of the planet itself.